# Alternative to switch, loop in javascript for multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, rest, switch-statement

I am implementing a rest API that **incorporates pagination and sorting.**

my query params:

- for paging - page (mandatory), limit ( optional).
- for sorting -  order_by(mandatory), sort_by(optional)

For a particular get request, a user can do the combination of the following operations:-

- use paging
- use paging + sorting
- use sorting
- use paging (without limit) + sorting( without sort_by)
- use paging (with limit) + sorting( with sort_by)

I was thinking to implement **switch** for this, by if in future additional query params are added then the list can go long

**so is there an alternative where I can mention multiple conditions ( in OR form) and doesn't loose performance too?**

Based on comments :- the same thing can be achieved by 5 if statements  but objective is to have scalable, readable and little performance ( if its possible)

```
function getResults(object) {
  var title = object.params
  switch (title) {
    case 'page':
      title = 'page'
      break
    case 'order_By':
      title = 'orderBy'
    default:
      title = 'Unassigned'
      break
  }
  .......( continued)
  return title
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you would need to switch on anything. if (sort) then sort; if (paging) then paginate;

Comment: i don't want to use 5 if statements, like my objective is to get this done in best performance and less code

Comment: *"best performance"* is not necessary most of the time. A few milli- (most likely nano) seconds extra delay is always better in if it increases the readability and scalability of your code

Comment: @Reyno i like the idea of readability and scalability, what would be your suggestions in this case? to go with switch or object literals or any other approach i am unaware of

Comment: I see only two cases that don't have to look at each others, so only two if ( and not if else, only 2 if). And the sort may have a sub condition

Comment: example i have added is for what i tried.@mmeisson,but i got your point

Comment: Do you want smaller code or better performance? The two are not necessarily correlated.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thats a tough choice :D but defintely i would go for something which has bette readability and scalability with some performance upgradation

Answer (score 0):

Just create an object a bit like this one

```
   Page
   PageSize (Limit i guess? Since paging in itself has no limit, just the pages)
   Sort
   SortDirection
```

I think this should suit you?

Then apply conditions via method. Example:

```
var myPagingObject = {};
function applyPagingParameter(key, value) {
 myPagingObject[key] = value;
}
```

No if statements need like that (except in the backend ofcourse, but if you standardize 4 if statements that can be used applicationwide, why not?)